# For a given $Y$ , what is the minimum variance of a $X$ such that $E[Y|X]=X$?

Tags: least-squares, exogeneity, minimum-variance

Suppose $Y$ is a given (real-valued continuous) random variable. We define any variable $X$ as exogenous to $Y$ if $\forall X: E[Y|X]=X$. The question is this: For a given $Y$ , What is the minimum variance of all $X$ exogenous to $Y$?
\Has this question been studied before?

Comment: How about zero, at $X = E[Y]$?

Comment: "We define any variable $X$ as exogenous to $Y$ if $\forall X: E[Y|X]=X$" looks peculiar.  Did you intend "if  $\forall x: E[Y\mid X=x]=x$"?  If so, the minimum variance of $Y$ would be the variance of $X$, in the case where $Y=X$ with probability $1$.  You can prove it with the law of total variance